# Is httpd / BIND required for a server running Gearman/Python?

Tags: apache-2.2, bind, httpd

We want to use a cloud server on an as required basis to to process some files.  There's no requirement to serve Webpages and we don't need to allocate a domain name to it. The server will just need to talk to our main Gearman Queue server, retrieve a job, access the file stored in the cloud, processes it and put it back in the cloud and advise the Gearman Queue that the job is complete.

Can we do this on a basic Centos OS box without Apache, httpd and BIND being set up?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not a server guy, more programming! Is there a yum package for the BIND client then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. If you aren't going to use them there is no reason to have daemons like apache installed or configured. You don't need a bind server either, just the client so you can resolve DNS addresses (likely useful to talk to your Gearman Queue server.)

In fact is is good practice to NOT install or run any software not actually being used.

Comment: I put the comment in the wrong place!! Thanks for that. I'm not a server guy, more programming! Is there a yum package for the BIND client then?

Comment: Yes, but I would be surprised if you have a system up and running without it. `ping google.com` and if it resolves to an IP address, you already have some sort of client installed so you don't need to worry about it.